# Reading gz file in Ruby using Zlib. Zlib::GzipReader is reading only the first line of the file and not all lines

Tags: ruby, file, ruby-on-rails-3, gzip, zlib

I have a `gz` file that I wanna parse. I am using `Zlib::GzipReader` library to open it.
In console I have the file like this:

```
164] pry(main)> file
=> #<Zlib::GzipReader:0x00007fadbbfa5a08>
[166] pry(main)> Zlib::GzipReader.open(file.path){|gz| print gz.read }
"Date","Connection type code","Connection id","Currency","Impressions","Campaign","Traffic source","Clicks","Cost (EUR)","Country"
=> nil
```

Notice that, after reading the file and printing. I just got the first line but in fact, the file contains lots of lines and I wanna have them all

Comment: Cannot reproduce with Ruby 2.6.3. Include exact steps to reproduce including: generation of text file, conversion to gzip file, setting `file` variable.

Comment: Are you running on Linux? try running `gzip -tv <filename>` to make sure the compressed file passes consistency checks

Comment: I just ran into the same problem with a file from the same source, judging by those headers.  I get all lines if I run it through `gunzip` and only the first line using the same method as above...   I'm currently using Ruby version 2.5.3p105.

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is related to [this bug](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9790):

> Zlib::GzipReader only decompressed the first of concatenated files.

Since it is still unsolved, you can use [multiple_files_gzip_reader](https://github.com/exAspArk/multiple_files_gzip_reader) gem to bypass Zlib's limitation.